# Back button iOS 7 phonegap history.back()

Tags: ios, cordova, back

I have a phonegap application running in iOS 7 on iPhone/iPad. 
I'm using

```
history.back()
```

method to come back to previous page but it doesn't work well. 
This is what I get:

1. I launch my app. Finished lunching it loads my home page;
2. I click on a link to load page 1;
3. I click on a `back` button with history back as a action and it doesn't work;
4. I click on a link to load page 2;
5. I click on a `back` button with history back as action...it WORKS and show page 1;
6. I click on a `back` button with history back as a action and it doesn't work again;

If when I launch my home page I reload it the `history.back` method work always...

Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem and have been trying to figure this one out for way to long. It seems like its a combination of data-ajax true or false, domcaching, etc. I'm using JQM, phonegap 3.0.0 to make a mobile, desktop, and IOS version that I want to work exactly the same

Here is what I did and it works so far. So basically if there are pages in history...show a back button, if not show the home button. I'll post more if I discover anything else.

```
function goBack(){
  history.go(-1);
  navigator.app.backHistory();
}

function goToUrl(x){
  window.location=x;
}

if (history.length>1) {
    backBtn = '<a href="javascript:goBack();" data-ajax="false" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>';
}else{
    backBtn = '<a href="javascript:goToUrl(\'../home/index.html\');" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left">Home</a>';
}
```